# Spring JPA Unique constraint violation when saving set

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am getting Unique constrain violation even though I am adding Unique delegation objects. Below is my mapping.

Workflow entity

```
@Table(name = "wkf_inst")

@Id
@Column(name = "WKF_INST_ID", updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer wkfInstId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wkfInstance", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = 
CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Delegation> Delegations;
```

Delegations entity

```
@Table(name = "wkf_assignee")
@Id
@Column(name = "WKF_INST_ASSIGNED_ID", updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer wkfDelegationId;

@Column(name = "ASSIGNED_TO")
private String delegatedTo;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "WKF_INST_ID")
private WkfInst wkfInstance;
```

We have unique constraint WKF_DELEGATION_UK on wkf_assignee table (WKF_INST_ID,ASSIGNED_TO).

I have added 4 delgation objects as a set to Workflow object and saving  wkfInstRepository.saveAndFlush(wkfInst).

Save throws unique constraint violation exception.

```
.d.i.w.controller.WorkflowController    : Update Workflow error for the workflow with instance ID : [248134]  [Co
mmon Workflow Engine] could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [WKF_DELEGATION_UK]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could 
not execute statement org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)
```

Delegation objects are extracted from a list as below.

```
`workflowInstance.getAssignedToList()
            .stream()
            .map(o -> {
                WkfDelegation delegation = new WkfDelegation();
                delegation.setDelegatedTo(o.getAssignedTo());
                delegation.setPriority(1);
                delegation.setDelegatedRoleId(o.getAssignedToRole());
                delegation.setIsActive("N");
                delegation.setWkfInstance(wkfInst);
                delegation.setDelegatedEmailId(o.getAssignedToEmailId());
                );
                return delegation;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());`
```

This delegations are set to workflow as below:

```
wkfInst.setWkfDelegations(getWorkFlowDelegations(workflowInstanceInfo, wkfInst));
```

Comment: And how do your 4 delgation objects look like??

Comment: @mrkernelpanic, I am extracting delegation data from a list. Updated in my post